# Change the size and proportions of the rectangle in shaders

Tags: javascript, glsl, shader

I'm new to new shaders and I'm trying to change the size and the proprotion of a rectangle, I found a way  to change the size but I'm failing to find a way to modify the proportions.

this is my fragment shader:

```c
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform float u_time;


void main(){
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;
    vec3 color = vec3(0.0);

    // bottom-left
    vec2 bl = step(vec2(0.1),st * 0.5);
    float pct = bl.x * bl.y;

    // top-right
    vec2 tr = step(vec2(0.1),(1.0-st) * 0.5);
    pct *= tr.x * tr.y;

    color = vec3(pct);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(color,1.0);
}
```

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

The bottom left corner is defined by `vec2(0.1)` int the line

> ```c
> vec2 bl = step(vec2(0.1),st * 0.5);
> ```

and the top right corner by `vec2(0.1)` (offset from the bottom left) in the line

> ```c
> vec2 tr = step(vec2(0.1),(1.0-st) * 0.5);
> ```

Note, `vec2(0.1)` constructs a 2 dimension vector with `x=0.1` and `y=0.1`.
`vec2(0.1)` constructs the same vector as `vec2(0.1, 0.1)`.

---

Define local variables for the bottom left and top right. e.g:

```c
vec2 bottomleft = vec2(0.3, 0.2);
vec2 topright   = vec2(0.7, 0.8);
```

and use it in the expressions. e.g:

```c
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform float u_time;

void main()
{
    vec2 bottomleft = vec2(0.3, 0.2);
    vec2 topright   = vec2(0.7, 0.8);

    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;

    vec2 bl = step(bottomleft, st); 
    vec2 tr = step(1.0-topright, 1.0-st);
    float pct = bl.x * bl.y * tr.x * tr.y;

    vec3 color = vec3(pct);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color,1.0);
}
```

---

Alternatively the rectangle can be defined by a bottom left origin and a size. e.g:

```c
void main()
{
    vec2 bottomleft = vec2(0.3, 0.2);
    vec2 size       = vec2(0.4, 0.6);

    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;

    vec2 bl = step(bottomleft, st); 
    vec2 tr = step(1.0-bottomleft-size, 1.0-st);
    float pct = bl.x * bl.y * tr.x * tr.y;

    vec3 color = vec3(pct);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color,1.0);
}
```